# Is this script a non-standard script?

Tags: script, non-standard-transaction

I am currently reviewing a computer science conference paper. The authors in the paper mention that the following is a non-standard script.

OP_DUP
OP_HASH160
OP_0
OP_EQUALVERIFY
OP_CHECKSIG

But when I checked the transaction on the explorer, its output script has NULL_DATA https://btc.com/btc/transaction/03acfae47d1e0b7674f1193237099d1553d3d8a93ecc85c18c4bec37544fe386

Which is the above two is true? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script is almost exactly the same as the standard Pay-To-Public-Key-Hash (P2PKH) script, except instead of pushing the hash onto the stack it pushes an empty vector.

As a reminder, a P2PKH script locks an output with the hash of a public key. To spend this output one must provide both the public key and a signature generated from its corresponding private key. Since the hash function always produces a 20-byte hash and never an empty vector, there is no public key to satisfy this script, making the output forever unspendable.

Why this output exists I can't tell you, but a [bitcointalk.org message](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=620203.msg7315697#msg7315697) mentions there are 23 of these. Most likely it's the result of a software bug.

NULL_DATA is probably just that specific blockchain explorer's label used for non-standard outputs. [mempool.space](https://mempool.space/tx/03acfae47d1e0b7674f1193237099d1553d3d8a93ecc85c18c4bec37544fe386) marks this as UNKNOWN.